# setBackground is messing up Thread.sleep

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics

I Have tried different ways to make two backgrounds for this snake game, one black for the menu and one white for the lines of the game. The best solution I found for this was using setBackground. But when I ran the game the the Thread.sleep got messed up and now the snake goes extremely fast. To try and trouble shoot this problem I put in multiple values into Thread.sleep but the snake travels at the same speed regardless of the values.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.Random;

public class Snake extends JPanel implements KeyListener, MouseListener{
    public  boolean right = false;
    public  boolean left = false;
    public  boolean up = false;
    public  boolean down = false;

    public int snakex[] = new int[10000000];
    public int snakey[] = new int[10000000];
    public int snakeLength = 0;

    public int applex;
    public int appley;

    public int buttonX = 150;
    public int buttonY = 125;

    public boolean appleEaten = true;

    public static boolean reset = false;
    public static boolean ingame = false;
    public static boolean menu = true;

    public static int speed = 200;

    public void forLogic(){
        for(int i = snakeLength; i > 1; i--){
            if(snakeLength > 4 &&  snakex[0] ==  snakex[i] && snakey[0] == snakey[i]){
                System.out.println("You Loose \n Your Score was: " + snakeLength);
                ingame = false;
            }
        }

        Movement();

        if(snakex[0] >= 30*20){
            snakex[0] = 0;
        }
        if(snakex[0] < 0){
            snakex[0] = 29*20;
        }
        if(snakey[0] >= 25*20){
            snakey[0] = 0;
        }
        if(snakey[0] < 0){
            snakey[0] = 24*20;
        }

        if(snakex[0] == applex*20 && snakey[0] == appley*20) {
            appleEaten = true;
            snakeLength++;
            //System.out.println(snakeLength);
        }

        if(appleEaten){
            appleLocation();
            appleEaten = false;
        }
    }

    public void appleLocation(){
        boolean goodToGo = false;
        Random rand = new Random();
        while(!goodToGo){
            applex = rand.nextInt(30);
            appley = rand.nextInt(25);
            boolean checker = false;
            for(int i = snakeLength; i > 0; i--) {
                if (applex == snakex[i]||appley == snakey[i]) {
                    checker = true;
                }
            }
            if(!checker){goodToGo = true;}
        }
    }

    public void Movement(){
        if(reset){
            left = false;
            right = false;
            up = false;
            down = false;

            snakex[0] = 0;
            snakey[0] = 0;
            snakeLength = 1;
            appleLocation();
            reset = false;
        }

        if(right){
            snakex[0] += 20;
        }
        if(left){
            snakex[0] -= 20;
        }
        if(up){
            snakey[0] -= 20;
        }
        if(down){
            snakey[0] += 20;
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        int mouseX = e.getX();
        int mouseY = e.getY();
        if(mouseX > buttonX && mouseX < buttonX + 300 && mouseY > buttonY && mouseY < buttonY + 75){
            ingame = true;
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == 39 && !left) {
            right = true;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if(key == 37 && !right){
            left = true;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if(key == 38 && !down){
            up = true;
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }
        if(key == 40 && !up){
            down = true;
            left = false;
            right = false;
        }
        if(key == 82){
            reset = true;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(menu){
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 50));
            g.drawString("Snake Game", 150, 50);
            g.drawRect(buttonX, buttonY, 300, 75);
            g.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 40));
            g.drawString("PLAY", 250, 175);
        }
        if(ingame) {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
                for (y = 0; y < 25; y++) {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.fillRect(x * 20, y * 20, 19, 19);
                }
            }

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(applex * 20, appley * 20, 19, 19);

            forLogic();

            g.setColor(Color.green);
            for (int i = snakeLength; i > 0; i--) {
                snakex[i] = snakex[(i - 1)];
                snakey[i] = snakey[(i - 1)];
                g.fillRect(snakex[i], snakey[i], 19, 19);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Snake Game");
        Snake snake = new Snake();
        jframe.add(snake);
        snake.addMouseListener(snake);
        snake.addKeyListener(snake);
        jframe.setSize(615, 540);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setFocusable(true);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        snake.requestFocusInWindow();
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        while(true) {
            if (!menu) {
                ingame = true;
            }
            if (menu == ingame) {
                ingame = false;
            }

            if (menu) {
                snake.repaint();
            }

            if (ingame) {
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    snake.repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've some major issues in that code of yours, including using `while (true)` loops and `Thread.sleep(...)` calls in your Swing code, overriding the paint method and calling the super paintComponent, a non-matching super method, within it (???), having game logic within a painting method. This suggests that a re-write using first principles would be very beneficial: use a Swing Timer for your game loop, use no other delaying code within your Swing code, override paintComponent and call the same super method within the override, separating painting from logic.

Comment: ... and calling `setBackground` within a paint method! This is potentially triggering a repaint, setting your logic off. This method should be called on JPanel creation, not repeatedly within a painting method.

Comment: Don't mix state management with your painting. Your game should have two different views, a menu and a game view, this allows each class to focus on there individual jobs and prevents unnecessarily complex code. [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536829/jlabel-not-showing-up-no-matter-what-i-do/33536969#33536969)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry for being blunt, but there is just so many problems with this code, it's hard to know where to begin.

---

## Problems:

- First off, you're calling `setBackground(...)` within a painting method, which is potentially triggering a repaint, which normally wouldn't be much of a problem...
- But you have your program logic being called from within your paint mehtod override, and this is a **major** problem. As you're finding out you don't have full or even partial control over when or even if a paint method is called or how often, and so having program logic within it is potentially deadly, and is likely causing your program to completely malfunction due to the setBackground call.
- You're also `while (true)` loops and `Thread.sleep(...)` calls in your Swing code, code that could completely freeze your GUI if the Swing code were initiated (as is supposed to be done) on the Swing event thread.
- You're overriding the paint method and yet calling the super paintComponent, a non-matching super method, within it, and this will break the Swing graphics chain, potentially resulting in significant painting irregularities.

  ---

## Suggestions:

- First and foremost, get all program logic outside of any and all painting methods.
- Remove all `Thread.sleep(...)` calls and `while (true)` loops.
- Use a Swing Timer, and advance your game "tick" within your Timer's ActionListener.
- Within this "tick", update the state of key fields in your program
- And then call `repaint();`.
- Override the `paintComponent` method only
- And within this override, call the same super method.
- Within paintComponent, use the modified fields to change what is painted and how.
- Call `setBackground(...)` once, in your class's constructor.
  having game logic within a painting method. This suggests that a re-write using first principles would be very beneficial: use a Swing Timer for your game loop, use no other delaying code within your Swing code, override paintComponent and call the same super method within the override, separating painting from logic.
- Read the tutorials. You're guessing which won't work here (as you're finding out).

---

## More

- Consider creating some non-GUI logic class.
- This can include, `GridPoint` for x and y position of each point on the grid
- Grid class a 2-dimensional array of GridPoint, the logical grid that holds the universe where the snake moves.
- SnakePoints which can include an `ArrayList<GridPoint>` that holds the ***logical*** position of the points on the snake.
- This last class can also have methods for adding a point, for moving the snake, for eating an apple.
- A Timer which would tell SnakePoints to advance one square

Answer (score 2):

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()`. Then you would still invoke super.paintComponent(g);

```
if(key == 39 && !left) {
```

Don't use magic numbers. The API will have variable for you to use. I'm guessing you want KeyEvent.VK_LEFT.

```
if(key == 82){
```

but I have no idea what that magic number is.

```
    if(ingame) {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Don't change properties of the component in a painting method. Painting methods are for painting only.

Maybe you need a method like setPlayingGame(Boolean). Then when true you set the properties for playing the game. When false you set the menu properties.

Or maybe even better you have two panels. One for the menu and one for the game. Then you use a CardLayout and swap panels depending on whether you want to paint the menu or the game.

You have too much game logic for me to debug what might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The snake is moving too fast because the method that "moves" the snake is being called too frequently. You are repainting every 200 milliseconds, but there is no sleep for the logic of the program. Your Thread.sleep should be in the logic part of the program:

```
public void forLogic(){
    for(int i = snakeLength; i > 1; i--){
        if(snakeLength > 4 &&  snakex[0] ==  snakex[i] && snakey[0] == snakey[i]){
            System.out.println("You Loose \n Your Score was: " + snakeLength);
            ingame = false;
        }
    }

    Movement();

    if(snakex[0] >= 30*20){
        snakex[0] = 0;
    }
    if(snakex[0] < 0){
        snakex[0] = 29*20;
    }
    if(snakey[0] >= 25*20){
        snakey[0] = 0;
    }
    if(snakey[0] < 0){
        snakey[0] = 24*20;
    }

    if(snakex[0] == applex*20 && snakey[0] == appley*20) {
        appleEaten = true;
        snakeLength++;
        //System.out.println(snakeLength);
    }

    if(appleEaten){
        appleLocation();
        appleEaten = false;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(speed);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```